# Radiobutton drawable ends up in incorrect state when in ViewPager

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-drawable, android-radiobutton

When my RadioButton is on the second page of my ViewPager (which is offscreen), it ends up looking like this when programmatically checked (in onViewCreated, onStart, and/or onResume)

[image: Incorrect state]

Ideally, the radiobutton should look like this

[image: Correct state]

How can I force the drawable to be in the correct state? I have tried invalidating the radio buttons but have had no luck. Clicking another radio button and re-clicking the correct one appears to fix the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After more testing, the issue appears to only be on API 25 and is caused by the animation that occurs when you click a RadioButton. I have fixed it by adding:

```
AnimatedStateListDrawable animatedStateListDrawable = (AnimatedStateListDrawable) radioButton.getButtonDrawable();
animatedStateListDrawable.jumpToCurrentState();
```

Answer (score 0):

Here instead of radio button you can use simply imageview and replace the image onclick of imageview and set the one of two images(one selected and other one deselected) accordingly. that is how you can maintain the state and its just look like radio button.